# HTML input type "time" not taking default value

Tags: html

I'm trying to use an HTML input element with `type="time"`, but I'm getting unexpected results. I have two of these on a page, one of them works and one does not.

```html
<td>
    <input type="time" class="uk-input" value="7:30:00" name="timein[]"/>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="time" class="uk-input" value="16:00:00" name="timeout[]"/>
</td>
```

The first element will be rendered blank, why?

Comment: See the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Time_value_format)

Comment: @Durga It states format `hh:mm:ss`, which thinking about it now obviously can mean it needs the leading 0, but it wasn't obvious to me at first and doesn't explicitly say this, thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

2 digits per number. Just add a 0 in front of 7. the format is `hh:mm:ss`.

Here is [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#Time_value_format).

```html
<input type="time" class="uk-input" value="07:30:00" name="timein[]"/>
<input type="time" class="uk-input" value="16:00:00" name="timeout[]"/>
```

Comment: Is this in documentation somewhere? I looked around and didn't see any mention of this

Comment: I'm not sure. Im only talking form experience.

Comment: Edit: only docuumentation i've found: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_input_time_value.asp

Comment: It looks like it does say the time format must be `hh:mm:ss` (I didn't previously see this), but if I didn't know better I still may have not seen that as "needs leading 0". Thank you! I will accept your answer when I can.

Comment: @Budyn `w3schools` is not everything. try to refer [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Comment: True, but it's respectable enough to quote and work from.